# Rstudio Statsbomb Error: parse error: premature EOF #20

Tags: r

I am new to statsbomb and R. Believe I got the initial packages installed correctly because it worked smoothly with the free data but when I attempt to use my account to access I am getting this parse errror: Preamture EOF shown below. I have defined username & password and have removed it below for obvious reasons. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
    Library(tidyverse)
    ── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────── tidyverse1.3.2 ──
    ✔ ggplot2 3.3.6 ✔ purrr 0.3.5
    ✔ tibble 3.1.8 ✔ dplyr 1.0.10
    ✔ tidyr 1.2.1 ✔ stringr 1.4.1
    ✔ readr 2.1.3 ✔ forcats 0.5.2
    ── Conflicts ─────────────────────────────────────────>tidyverse_conflicts() ──
    ✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
    ✖ dplyr::lag() masks stats::lag()
    library(StatsBombR)
    Loading required package: stringi
    Loading required package: rvest

    Attaching package: ‘rvest’

    The following object is masked from ‘package:readr’:

    guess_encoding

    Loading required package: RCurl

    Attaching package: ‘RCurl’

    The following object is masked from ‘package:tidyr’:

    complete

    Loading required package: doParallel
    Loading required package: foreach

    Attaching package: ‘foreach’

    The following objects are masked from ‘package:purrr’:

    accumulate, when

    Loading required package: iterators
    Loading required package: parallel
    Loading required package: httr
    Loading required package: jsonlite

    Attaching package: ‘jsonlite’

    The following object is masked from ‘package:purrr’:

    flatten

    Loading required package: sp
    Warning messages:
    1: replacing previous import ‘foreach::when’ by ‘purrr::when’ when loading ‘StatsBombR’
    2: replacing previous import ‘jsonlite::flatten’ by ‘purrr::flatten’ when loading ‘StatsBombR’
    3: replacing previous import ‘foreach::accumulate’ by ‘purrr::accumulate’ when loading ‘StatsBombR’
    username = ""
    password = ""
    comps <- competitions(username, password)
    Error: parse error: premature EOF

    (right here) ------^"
```

Comment: Are there any non-alphanumeric characters in your strings?

Comment: Yes the @ in the username but I have even tried without and any combination and still get the same error